# MS Flow time-out after 30 days

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, flow, powerapp, power-automate

We started using SharePoint Online and looking to use MS  Flow and PowerApps for our workflows however MS Flow run expire after 30 days and it did not meet our requirement as there are approvals that runs more than that.

Is there any solution / workaround on this limitation?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is, it depends.

If you want to build the approval as a single flow, then the answer is no for the reasons given by @Michael Han_MSFT.

However, you could build a set of flows that implement an approval process that lasts longer than 30 days. Just note that building such a process is complex and will require that you use premium features of Power Automate.

There are several proposed architectures out there for this type of approval process. You can find them by searching for "Microsoft Flow long running approval".

I recently built a prototype for a long-running approval process that is made up of three flows that use the Approvals connector, the HTTP connector, and the Common Data Service connector. I hope to have a blog post or video that explains how I built my prototype out soon.

Comment: Thanks hoping on to see that soon.

Answer (score 1):

As a short answer, No.

The Run duration and Storage retention of Microsoft Flow is 30 days. Which means that after 30 days, related data will be gone. Besides, it is from the run start time.

After 30 days, any pending steps time-out. Timed-out approvals are removed from the approvals center. If someone attempts to approve a timed-out request, they will receive an error message.

Please check this article for more:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/limits-and-config